# Webhook or other notifications when Azure App Service rotates the underlying instance VMs

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

We have our Azure App Service set to a dedicated number of instances (> 1). We have noticed in Application Insights Live Metrics that periodically, App Service will rotate out one of the underlying VMs and replace it with a new instance. We noticed this because during the rotation, the requests/sec for *all* instances drops to almost 0 for about a minute, before they all ramp back up to normal again.

- Are there any webhooks or other notification mechanisms we can subscribe to to learn when these rotations happen, and, more importantly, why?
- Are these VM swaps documented anywhere?
- Is there some way to prevent the requests/sec from dropping for the remaining, "healthy" VMs while this swap occurs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [Health Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet) for you web app and configure an Activity Alert when this metric is <100%. This will allow to determine if your [instance became unhealthy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-instance-related-issues-on-azure-app-service). With regards to mitigation steps, you can take when the instance becomes unhealth, this [guide](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/05/15/Robust-Apps-for-the-cloud.html) contains steps you can take to ensure your app is highly available.